# Datasets & Tutorials specifically targeting Business Data Analysis Issues

Tags: python, dataset, data-science, kaggle

I am looking for data sets and tutorials which are specifically targeting business data analysis issues. I know about Kaggle but it's main focus is on Machine learning and associated problems/issues. Would be great to know a blog or dump regarding data analysis issues. Or may be a good read/book?

Comment: Tutorial and offsite resource recommendation questions are expressly off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer to this all depends on how comfortable you are currently with machine learning. Business data analysis and predictions are so closely aligned with machine learning that most developers consider it a subset that more general ML skills will cover. So I will suggest two things to you. If you have no experience in ML launch into the Data Science(python) career track of Data camp - It is excellent! This will help you get to grips with the overall ideas of cleaning your data and data processing, as well as supervised and unsupervised learning.

If you are already comfortable with all that I would suggest looking at pbpython.com - This site covers python for business analysis use entirely and suggests a plethora of books specialized for certain topics. As well as covering individual topics itself very well.